# Cypress: Mime type issue involving - Possibly Okta related

Tags: testing, cypress

When using Cypress to attempt to goto and login a webpage. The webpage shows up blank (Cypress does not note an error) and the console gives this error.

Hitting the same site without Okta SSO does not have the same problem. Due to some company security practices for now I have to figure out a way to get to the page with Okta involved.

This is the error I receive from the console

> Refused to apply style from (Okta redirect) because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

As I don't have control over the redirect or content-type that Okta is throwing up in the middle I can't change anything from my side.

Comment: Could you provide some minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: as above comment, please write some examples here